# What dependency registrations should I change in ASP.NET Core 2.1 if I change the Identity primary key?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac, asp.net-core-identity

I changed the primary key according to this [Configure Identity primary key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-primary-key-configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x)

and this exception will occur:

> ComponentNotRegisteredException: The requested service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser, Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]]' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.

I tried to register UserManager but unsuccessfully.

Here is Startup.cs

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        //services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        //  options.UseSqlServer(
        //      Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddDbContext<IdentityContext>();

        services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityContext>()
            .AddDefaultUI()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


        services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
            .AddControllersAsServices();

        // AUTOFAC
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.Populate(services);
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(ServiceBase).Assembly).AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        return new AutofacServiceProvider(builder.Build());
    }
```

Before I changed the primary key, dependency injection worked.

Comment: It's asking for the `UserManager<IdentityUser>` registration. I don't see that registered here. Where are you registering that? If you aren't doing that yourself, where in the base ASP.NET Core identity code is that being registered?

Comment: It looks like you've added `AppUser` in order to customise the key type, so you need to update your use of `UserManager<IdentityUser>` to `UserManager<AppUser>` whenever you get it from the DI container.

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7856